# convert objective C protocol to equivalent in c++

Tags: c++, objective-c

i am porting a game from Obj-C to C++. And stuck  where I have to convert Obj-C protocol to equivalent in C++. I am confused what should be the right way to achieve same functionality in C++.

Please advise.

```
@protocol A <NSObject>

    -(void) B:(NSObject*)data;

@end


@interface callBack: NSObject
{
    id<A*> delegate;
}
```

Comment: Closest C++ concept is multiple inheritance.

Comment: Which part of the conversion are you having trouble with? I see no question here.

Comment: let me give you a snippet of code. Thanks.

Comment: Related questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182700/whats-the-c-equivalent-of-the-obj-c-delegate-pattern) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752500/objective-c-protocol-equivalent-in-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve something similar to a protocol making a class with pure `virtual` methods.
Conforming to that protocol will require to override such methods.

The "protocol" declaration

```
class ImageDelegate {
    public:
        virtual void getImage(UIImage *) = 0;
}
```

Then refer to `ImageDelegate*` as you would do with `id<ImageDelegate>`

```
class ResInfoCallback : public NSObject {
    public:
       ImageDelegate *delegate;
}
```

Finally you need a class implementing the "protocol", which means overriding the pure `virtual` methods of the "protocol" class.

```
class YourClassConformingToTheProtocol : public ImageDelegate {
    public:
        virtual void getImage(UIImage *image) {
            //do stuff
        }
}
```

As a final remark **PLEASE** use capitalized names for classes.

Comment: excellent..thanks a lot for a prompt help. This is what i was looking for :-)