# Objective-C @protocol equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, delegates

Class A has an instance of class B as a member. Sometimes the instance of class B wants to talk to class A. In Objective-C I can do:

```
// A.h
@interface A : NSObject <BDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) B *b;
@end 

// A.m
- (void) classBsays {

}


// B.h
@protocol BDelegate
- (void) classBsays;
@end

@interface B : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<BDelegate> delegate;
@end

// B.m
@implementation B
- (void) f {
    [delegate classBsays];
}
@end
```

I've done something similar in C++ using a void pointer on class B. But this misses the part that says "class B's delegate should implement such and such methods".

**How can I imitate Objective-C's protocol in C++?**

Comment: A C++ class with only pure virtual member functions (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318064) for a basic intro) is roughly equivalent to an Objective-C protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ equivalent of your example looks something like this:

```cpp
// A.hpp
#include "B.hpp"

class A : public BDelegate {
    public:
        void classBSays ( ) { }
        B* b;
};

// B.hpp
class BDelegate {
    public:
        virtual void classBSays( ) = 0;
};
class B {
    public:
        void f ( ) { delegate->classBSays( ); }
        BDelegate* delegate;
};
```

Note that I've used inline implementation of the member functions here, for brevity's sake - you could equally implement `A.classBSays()` and `B.f()` in separate `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` files if you wanted.

In this example, the class `BDelegate` is an abstract base class (ABC), equivalent to your `BDelegate` protocol. By containing only pure virtual member functions (functions preceded with the keyword `virtual` and with the `=0` suffix), it forces its subclasses to provide implementations for those methods, much as using a `@required` tag (or no tag) does in an Objective-C protocol. The fact that `BDelegate` contains only such functions is what makes it an ABC.

You can emulate the Objective-C `@optional` tag by specifying an empty body for the function in your ABC, which means that subclasses are not required to implement it (since it is implemented in the ABC). For example, you could emulate an optional `foo` method by modifying the `BDelegate` as follows:

```
@protocol BDelegate
- (void) classBsays;
@optional
- (void) foo;
@end
// Is approximately equivalent to:
class BDelegate {
    public:
        virtual void classBSays( ) = 0;
        virtual void foo( ) { }
};
```

Using that definition, the class `A` could choose whether to provide a definition for `foo` or not, as is desired. Note however that this is not exactly equivalent to the Objective-C `@optional` notation, because `A` will still inherit `BDelegate`'s `foo` method if it doesn't provide it's own override. With the Objective-C protocol, on the other hand, `A` would have no such method at all unless it explicitly implements it itself.

A more thorough introduction to the subject is available [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve basically the same in C++ by defining an abstract base class. That is, you only define method signatures and do not provide any implementation. This requires any subclasses to implement the declared methods.

Here is your example translated to C++:

```
// A.h
class A : public BDelegate {
    B *b;
};

// A.m
Result A::classBsays {

}

// B.h
class BDelegate {
    virtual Result classBsays() = 0;
};

class B {
    BDelegate* delegate;
};

// B.m
void B::f {
    delegate->classBsays();
}
```

Note that this will probably not compile, as it is missing a few important things. You would need a constructor, pass in the B reference, probably even use a `std::shared_ptr` for the delegate, and so on.  But the general shape is something like this.

The important part is the method declaration for `BDelegate::classBsays()` has the `= 0` after the method signature, and has no implementation body.  This means the method is **pure virtual**, which means a subclass *must* implement the method or it cannot be instantiated.  (Which makes sense, otherwise you could potentially call a method that has no implementation!)  Any class that has one or more pure virtual methods is itself a pure virtual class.  This is very commonly used just as you describe, to define interfaces that decouple different parts of the system.

Comment: a protocol can also define optional methods, which would be catered by virtual methods with an {} implementation, rather than being declared as pure virtual

Comment: @Petesh: that's probably the closest equivalent, but is not exactly the same. In particular, if the C++ `BDelegate` class contained a `virtual foo(){}` function, then you can be guaranteed that `A` has such a member function. On the other hand, if the Objective-C `BDelegate` protocol contains an `@optional -(void) foo;`, then `A` may or may not have a `foo` method (depending entirely on whether it is explicitly implemented in `A` or not).

Comment: ... and the caller may determine the fact that an optional method is implemented or not and change its behaviour accordingly in a way that cannot be achieved by a default implementation in some base class.